# Unirest howto log request and response in Java

Tags: log4j, unirest

I just started using Unirest REST framework which is great
but don't see anywhere option to intercept and log full request and response with headers and body.
Does anybody know how to atchieve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Unirest.config()
  .intercepter(new LoggingInterceptor());
```

LoggingInterceptor.java

```
public class LoggingInterceptor implements kong.unirest.Interceptor {
  
  @Override
  public void onRequest(HttpRequest<?> request, Config config) {
    // Log request
  }
  
  @Override
  public void onResponse(HttpResponse<?> response, HttpRequestSummary request, Config config) {
    // Log response
  }

}
```

Answer (score -4):

Please refer to their documentation page. It has details on maven integration, how to make http request, query etc on it.
Link: http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/